# How to show that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A/(b), K/A)$ is isomorphic to $A/(b)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $A$ be a integral domain and let $K$ be its field of fractions.
>
> Show that for any $b \in A$,
>
> $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A/(b), K/A)$ is isomorphic to $A/(b)$.

So I have a few questions.

**1.** I don't quite understand the notation $K/A$. Can someone explain it to me?

**2.** How do I begin the first step, that is to construct a homomorphism ?

Comment: $K$ is an $A$-module and $A$ is a submodule. So $K/A$ is just the usual quotient.

Comment: The assertion is false for $b=0$.

Comment: @MooS What makes you think so?

Comment: Its obviously false for $b=0$. The Hom set is equal to $K/A$ then which is not isomorphic to $A$.

Comment: @MooS You're right, thank you, I deleted the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following general fact is well known: $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/I,M) = \{m \in M ~|~ Im=0\}$.

Let $b \neq 0$.

In our case, this yields $\operatorname{Hom}_A(A/(b),K/A) = \{x \in K/A ~|~ bx=0\}$.

$bx=0 \in K/A$ means $bx \in A$, i.e. $x = \frac{a}{b} \in \langle \frac{1}{b} \rangle$ for some $a \in A$. Thus we have shown the desired

$$\operatorname{Hom}_A(A/(b),K/A) = \{x \in K/A | bx=0\} = \langle \frac{1}{b} \rangle \cong A/(b).$$

---

For the sake of completion: For $b=0$, we have

$$\operatorname{Hom}_A(A/(b),K/A) = \operatorname{Hom}_A(A/,K/A) = K/A \not\cong A = A/(b),$$

i.e. the statement is true for $b \neq 0$, but false for $b=0$.

Comment: Thank you Moos for this and a previous question you answered.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assume $b\ne0$, because in this case the result is false.

Given $a\in A$, you can define $\tilde{a}\colon A\to K/A$ by
$$
\tilde{a}(x)=\frac{ax}{b}+A
$$
(when $b\ne0$). It is clear that $(b)\subseteq\ker\tilde{a}$, so $\tilde{a}$ defines $\hat{a}\colon A/(b)\to K/A$ by
$$
\hat{a}(x+(b))=\frac{ax}{b}+A
$$
It's easy to verify that $a\mapsto\hat{a}$ is a homomorphism
$$
\varphi\colon A\to \operatorname{Hom}_A(A/(b),K/A)
$$
If $a\in (b)$, then $\tilde{a}$ is the zero map, so also $\hat{a}=0$. Conversely, if $\hat{a}=0$, we have
$$
\hat{a}(1+(b))=\frac{a}{b}+A=A
$$
that is, $a\in(b)$. Thus $\varphi$ induces a monomorphism
$$
\tilde{\varphi}\colon A/(b)\to\operatorname{Hom}_A(A/(b),K/A)
$$
and it remains to show that $\varphi$ is surjective. This will follow when we show that any homomorphism $f\colon A\to K/A$ that vanishes on $(b)$ is of the form $\tilde{a}$, for some $a$. Let
$$
f(1)=\frac{t}{u}+A
$$
so $f(x)=\frac{tx}{u}+A$. By assumption $f$ vanishes on $b$, so
$$
\frac{tb}{u}\in A
$$
and we are done by choosing $a=tb/u$.

Comment: One question though, how do we know $a = \frac{tb-ub}{u}$ is in $A$ ?

Comment: @some1fromhell Yes, it's false in that generality, but we just need that $f$ vanishes on $(b)$. Fixed.